# MYSQL loop to collect data from more that one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables that i need to collect data from to build my report. 
the first table has the grouping code and the car make and models 
eg Sxcode_id  decription
   1050       Chrysler Jeep
   105001     Liberty
so the first four numbers is the Make of the Sxcode_id and the next numbers are the models of the make.
I have been able to get just the Make from the database to build my headings in the report.

```
$query1 = ("SELECT * From `sxcodecar` WHERE Sxcode_id IN (SELECT        LEFT(Sxcode_id,4) FROM `sxcodecar`) ");
     $mysqlquery1 = mysqli_query($link,$query1);

  //Select into an array
  while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlquery1)) {
        $new_array[$row1['Sxcode_id']]['Sxcode_id'] = $row1['Sxcode_id'];
        $new_array[$row1['Sxcode_id']]['Decription'] = $row1['Decription'];
    }

 //this gets the make of the car from the array
 foreach($new_array as $array) {
      $car = $array["Sxcode_id"];

        echo "Car Make -" . $array["Decription"]. "<br>";

  }
```

what i am trying to do now is get the data from the other tables and put it under each heading so my next table has the Sxcode_id and the product_code and the Product Description, and the last table has the product_code and the retail price.

so what i want is a report like this.

Heading  Make of car ie ford

models car Ranger

Product_code and Descriptions for that car

I am not sure do i put the SQL select in the foreach loop or a while loop

this is what i have been playing with.

```
 //test one to get the product details
 $query3 = ("SELECT * FROM `sxcodelink` ");

 ///test 2 trying to link the tables
  //$query3 = ("SELECT sxcodelink.product_code, sxcodelink.Decription,     stockprice.retail_price FROM sxcodelink FULL OUTER JOIN stockprice ON sxcodelink.product_code=stockprice.product_code ");

 //Test 3 linking the tables again 
 //$query3 = ("SELECT * FROM sxcodelink FULL OUTER JOIN stockprice ON sxcodelink.product_code=stockprice.product_code WHERE sxcodelink.Sxcode_id LIKE  '$car%' GROUP BY `sxcodelink.Sxcode_id`");

     $mysqlquery3 = mysqli_query($link,$query3);

   $query2 = ("SELECT * From `sxcodecar` WHERE Sxcode_id LIKE '$car%' GROUP BY `Sxcode_id` ");
 //$query2 = ("SELECT * From `sxcodecar` WHERE SUBSTR(Sxcode_id, 1,4) = '$car' GROUP BY `Sxcode_id` ");
    $mysqlquery2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);

  $query1 = ("SELECT * From `sxcodecar` WHERE Sxcode_id IN (SELECT LEFT(Sxcode_id,4) FROM `sxcodecar`) ");
  $mysqlquery1 = mysqli_query($link,$query1);
     while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlquery1)) {
         $new_array[$row1['Sxcode_id']]['Sxcode_id'] = $row1['Sxcode_id'];
          $new_array[$row1['Sxcode_id']]['Decription'] = $row1['Decription'];
   }


 if ($mysqlquery3){ //Query connection
      $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqlquery3);
}
 else
 {
 echo 'MYSQL Query Failed';
echo $result;
 }

 ?>
 <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <?php
   foreach($new_array as $array) {
        $car = $array["Sxcode_id"];

       echo "Car Make -" . $array["Decription"]. "<br>";



  }

//echo $car;
    //the next selection

    //while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlquery2)) {
        //echo "Car Make -" . $row1["Decription"]. "<br>";
        //echo "Car Make -" . $array["Decription"]. "<br>";
        //echo "Cars   " .$row2["Decription"]. "<br>";
        //while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlquery3)) {
            //echo $row3["products_code"];
            //echo "   " . $row3["Description"] ;
            //echo  "  " . $row3["stockprice.retail_price"]. "<br>";



    //      }

 ?>
```

I do apologize if any does not like my code layout this is my test code just trying to understand the select request. and any help is appreciated, and i hope you understand what i am trying to do

Comment: JOIN the tables instead of connecting them in PHP.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: JOINs are the second or third thing you should learn when learning SQL. There are many tutorials that will help you with this.